# HOC example in React+Typescript doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create an HOC example in React+Typescript, but my code doesn't work.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pyo31r4xlx)

This is the HOC component:

**Hello.jsx**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface Props {
  name: string;
  itemClicked: () => void;
}

interface State {
  inc: number;
}

export const makeHello = <P extends Props>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  class Hello extends React.Component<Props, State> {
    constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        inc: 0
      };
    }

    itemClicked = () => {
      this.setState({ inc: inc + 1 }, () => {
        console.log("itemClicked");
      });
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <Component itemClicked={this.itemClicked} {...this.props}>
          Inc state is: {this.state.inc}!
        </Component>
      );
    }
  };

export default makeHello;
```

And component `ChildHello`:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Props } from "./Hello";
import { makeHello } from "./Hello";

export class ChildHello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: ""
  };

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.props.itemClicked}>Child component</div>;
  }
}

export default makeHello(ChildHello);
```

I don't get any error, but method `itemClicked` in `Hello.jsx` is not triggered when I click `div` element in `ChildHello.tsx`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you made an import/export mistake.

You were importing the named class from the ChildHello instead of the HOC wrapped default export.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Props } from "./Hello";
import makeHello from "./Hello";

// In index.tsx import { ChildHello } refers to this, not the default export below
export class ChildHello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: ""
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this);
    return <div onClick={this.props.itemClicked}>Child component</div>;
  }
}

export default makeHello(ChildHello);
```

In your index.tsx make sure you remove the named import

```
import ChildHello from "./ChildHello";
```

Then in your Hello.tsx update the itemClicked method, because it's erroring out

```
// UPDATED added "this.state" to inc
this.setState({ inc: this.state.inc + 1 }, () => {
```